# What english words can be created using hexadecimal?

Tags: hex

I'm setting up an old wireless router for a friend which uses WEP (Yeah, very old, not actually very secure, but enough to keep the non-technical people in her apartment complex from sucking bandwidth) and I need to have a 10 digit hexadecimal key as the password.

So the question is, what english words can be made using the hexadecimal character set:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 A B C D E F
```

BEEF is an example.  I think that leet character would be allowed as well, So the number 0 could be used for the letter o.  This lets you make the word BEA7.

Comment: not programming related but... beef, feed, bee, bade, bad, bead, dead, deed, deaf, add, ace, cede

Comment: egrep -i '[a-foilstge]+' /usr/share/dict/words | tr oilstge 0115793 | tr A-Z a-z

Comment: Because of the way you worded this, it may not be programming appropriate, but in actuality, embedded programmers use these regularly to make memory dumps and debugging easier to visualize.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Java CAFEBABE, COFEEBABE or DEADBEEF for instance. You might like to check [HexWords](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/HexWords.htm) or [Ned Batchelder Hex Words](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/hexwords.html) for a lot more examples.

Comment: While you *can* spell out `0xC0FFEEBABE` in hex, `0xCAFEBABE` is the magic number that starts every Java class file. http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/whyCAFEBABE.html

Comment: My favorite one is `deface`, as it is long, strict hex and a well known IT security concept. I also like `decade`. Phrases are also cool: `a dead beef bedded a defaced babe`

Comment: You can switch more with leet speak so get things like: codifiabilities c0d1f1ab11171e5, decasyllabics deca5711ab1c5, decidabilities dec1dab11171e5, fatalistically fa7a11571ca117, badasses bada55e5, database da7aba5e, effaced

Comment: My favorite: "effedface" -- aa, ab, aba, abaca, abba, abbe, abed, accede, acceded, ace, aced, ad, add, added, ae, aff, ba, baa, baaed, baba, babe, bacca, baccae, bad, bade, baff, baffed, be, bead, beaded, bed, bedad, bedded, bee, beebee, beef, beefed, cab, cabbed, caca, cad, cade, caeca, caf, cafe, caff, ceca, cede, ceded, cee, da, dab, dabbed, dace, dad, dada, daff, daffed, de, dead, deaf, deb, decade, decaf, dee, deed, deeded, def, deface, defaced, ebb, ebbed, ed, ef, eff, efface, effaced, fa, fab, facade, face, faced, fad, fade, faded, faff, faffed, fe, fed, fee, feeb, feed

Comment: Just realized: 0xDecafC0ffee